# GET var not working properly? Example inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, request

This is hurting my head. In a func i haave the code below. What is hurting my head is the fact i can se &id= in my RawUrl and it the value it should hold meanwhile req["id"] in the if statement returns null

```
    var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    string u = req.RawUrl; // --> /pstcm&id=5653999025705172077
    d = null;
    if (req["id"] != null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see, the `id=...` is not specified as a querystring attribute. There's no `?` before it. It's part of the URL path itself. The indexer of `HttpRequest` will only consider cookies, form values, querystring attributes, and server variables. Obviously, it cannot magically infer any arbitrarily defined format.

Comment: Isnt ?key=val&k2=v2 etc all GET variables? arent get vars part of querystring?

Comment: Yes. `Request[...]` will get not only get vars, but also POST, cookies and server vars. This is unrelated to your question though. Your problem is `/pstcm&id=5653999025705172077` doesn't have a question mark in it. The whole thing is part of the path. Probably you meant to say: `/pstcm?id=5653999025705172077`

Comment: D'oh! now i see it. I construct the URL automatically in another piece of code. I never considered there may be not be any GET vars in the url and just did &... always. Oops. I corrected it. Thanks.